# How can I set my wireless router to run on a time schedule?

Tags: cron, wifi, buffalo

I have a Buffalo AirStation WZR-HP-G301NH
I am able to access it's settings via 192.168.11.1
I'm connecting wirelessly with toshiba i686 laptop on Linux Mint Debian with service pack 3 and i686 dual core kernel

This is just my home network but I know that there must be a way for large industries to shut their networks down or lock out their network access temporarily based on a time schedule, automatically.

Like mon - fri the network provides access from 8am to 10pm and then automatically shuts down. I want this to affect all the computers accessing this netowork... basically all my families computers so that the internet just automatically shuts down at bedtime.

I am running Linux Mint Debian and so maybe I need to make a cron job or something but does anyone know how big industries implement this and how I can do it privately?

TIA

Comment: Your easiest solution is to but a wall plug timer 6hat turns the power on and off at a given time for the router device

Comment: that is a great idea. I hadn't thought of that. I did find out that my router actually comes with a scheduling system built in O_o I just set it up with my wife and it does it all automatically. Most new routers come with this functionality built in. It was hard for me to find because my router is Japanese and I couldn't read the config page. But I found it and all is well.

Comment: @lain I do have however a little box with a lock on it that I put the phone dsl cable into and have my wife lock it when she goes out. Only she knows the padlock combo. It works great for when she's out but not so great for time schedules but anyways. problem solved. thanks

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about how larger businesses would implement this - they would use similar functionality to what your router has built-in. For example Microsoft's ISA/TMG server has fine-grained control over web access so that particular users are restricted to certain websites / times of day etc.

In general terms there will be something on the network that all outbound (ie. Internet) traffic will be routed through - be it Linux, Microsoft or whatever - that can perform filtering.